# Переотправка сообщения обратно в очередь в RabbitMQ

Tags: python, любой-язык, rabbitmq

Как RabbitMQ настроить так, чтобы переотправка сообщения из очереди, скажем queue, в случае неудачной обработки снова попало в очередь queue и обработалось через определенное время ?

Comment: А через Scheduler пробовали?

Comment: @And Нет, можно подробнее ?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/

Comment: @And не поулчается поставить. Ошибка: `Error: The following plugins could not be found:
  rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange`

Comment: Ну видимо Вы, что - то забыли импортнуть, смотря, что вы пытаетесь запустить и на каком языке, если на jython(phyton) - предется импортнуть реализацию java. Про импорты явы http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/usejava.html

Comment: @And а на CPython это сработает ?

Comment: По идее да: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам уже сообщали, через плагин отложенных сообщений данную концепцию можно реализовать. Но, скажу как человек использующий данный плагин в продакшен. Сделайте систему мониторинга целостности данных. Потому как есть болезнь у этого плагина. Сообщения могут не возвращаться после истечения времени и накапливаться в обменнике. Лечится перезагрузкой реббита, но с потерей сообщений в обменнике